# Azure B2C Auth Development Mode

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create an ASP.Net Core 3 webapp that uses Azure B2C for authentication. I created a WebApp using the template in Visual Studio and have configured the appsettings.json with appropriate values.

The app launches fine and when I click the *Sign In* button, I receive the following error:

[image: Error]

However when I `dotnet run` from Code, I can see the following:

[image: Hosting Env = Development]

`Hosting environment = Development` which I think contradicts the error message.
When I click *Sign In* I can briefly see I am being redirected to AzureB2C which is sending me back.

How can I set Development mode to reveal more about the error here?

Edit:
`Startup.cs` is not changed from the default using the WebApp template with B2C selected as auth.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show you have configure the middleware in Configure() (in Startup class)?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a testing on a development perspective you can move the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to outside the `if` and comment that `if else`, that way you should be able to see the problem when debugging the app again.

Also, for your error message a commom error is a misconfiguration of user attributes on the user flows, try to add de Azure ID and email there (you should be able to access that following `Azure AD B2C > User Flows > Select the flow > Declarations` on your tenant portal.